# android drop the dragged object onto another object

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I'm testing my drag and drop android game. I got the dragging thing working, but I want the dragged object(imageview) to be dropped onto another imageview (in my code I use objBasket)

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
  mainLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("touch", "touched here" + event);

            if(status == 1) // any event from down and move
            {
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        (int)event.getX()-iv.get(0).getWidth()/2,
                        (int)event.getY()-iv.get(0).getHeight()/2);
                iv.get(0).setLayoutParams(lp);

            } else if(status == 2){
                    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            (int)event.getX()-iv.get(1).getWidth()/2,
                            (int)event.getY()-iv.get(1).getHeight()/2);
                    iv.get(1).setLayoutParams(lp);
            } else if(status == 3){
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        (int)event.getX()-iv.get(2).getWidth()/2,
                        (int)event.getY()-iv.get(2).getHeight()/2);
                iv.get(2).setLayoutParams(lp);
            } else if(status == 4){
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        (int)event.getX()-iv.get(3).getWidth()/2,
                        (int)event.getY()-iv.get(3).getHeight()/2);
                iv.get(3).setLayoutParams(lp);
            }


            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                status = 0;

                iv.get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                iv.get(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                iv.get(2).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                iv.get(3).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                status = 0;



            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

My problem is what method should I use in the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN? I'm kinda new to drag and drop thingy so I beg your pardon. Has anybody here already done the same thing? Please give me suggestions or sample code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On motion down you should either use whether your point (x, y) belongs to some of your images below, or you can see whether two of them intersects with their bound Rects

Comment: @MarkoLazić thanks for your question, do  you have sample code to get me started? THanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a way I check whether two views Rect bounds intersect

```
private boolean checkHit(View v, View hit){
    Rect rv = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    Rect rhit = new Rect(hit.getLeft(), hit.getTop(), hit.getRight(), hit.getBottom());
    return rv.intersect(rhit);
}
```

and this whether point belongs

```
private boolean checkHit(MotionEvent event, View hit){      
    Rect rhit = new Rect(hit.getLeft(), hit.getTop(), hit.getRight(), hit.getBottom());
    return rhit.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY());
}
```

Then just go through your views of interest and...

EDIT:
Call in your ACTION_UP Part something like this, I did this in switch case you in if statements

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:         
            drop(v, event);
        break;
```

and drop method

```
private void drop(View v, MotionEvent event){
   checkHit(v, view2beHit);
   checkHit(event, view2beHit);
   // Do some for looping, do some other magic, do what you want
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Hi I beg your pardon, I still don't understand where will I embed this code?

Comment: Can I set their same absolute location when the view2behit and viewtohit?